# Linking Libraries using f2py

Tags: python, numpy, linker, fortran, f2py

I have a fortran program that uses some library files. I am trying to link them along with the module file being created.

The library file I am trying to link is called `ulib.a` and is located in the directory `/home/replace/lib/`

The command I am using is:

```
f2py -L/home/replace/lib/ -lulib.a -c main.f -m progs
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lulib.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lulib.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: A static library is just a set of object files, so you can include directly as `f2py -c main.f /home/replace/ulib.a -m progs` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Try leaving off the .a - I am reasonably sure that the linker already knows that libraries are .a so in your example it will be looking for ulib.a.a and failing.

Comment: Also the library name should start with `lib` and you include only `-fname` if the library is called `libname.a`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove the extension from the library name and also provide the full path. For some reason providing the path using the `-L` argument did not work.

```
f2py -l/home/replace/lib/ulib -c main.f -m progs
```

Comment: So Steve Barnes' suggestion did not work? I've been doing it that way, and it's worked for me.

Comment: I have to use this way also (only -l and not -L+-l).  I'm on windows with version 2 of f2py.

Answer (score 0):

The library should have the full name `libxxx.a` where `xxx` is the given name. Then do

```
f2py -L. -lxxx -c main.f90 -m progs
```

Note that only `xxx` comes after `-l`. If you create the library yourself remember to include `-fPIC`. For example, it could look like this:

```
gfortran -c -fPIC source1.f90 source2.f90
ar crs libxxx.a obj1.o obj2.o
f2py -L. -lxxx -c main.f90 -m progs
```

Found guidance in this example: https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs/DOC-2343

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is very useful. (1) the OP says the library is in a different folder, which must be referenced. (2) Beyond that, what is different about this answer compared to the current one?